# Delphi7: How to get icon from ImageList with blend color gray

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, grayscale, notifyicon, imagelist

All methods blend with system highlight blue color.

```
ImageList1.BlendColor := clGray;
ImageList1.DrawingStyle := dsSelected;

ImageList1.GetIcon(0, icon);    
ImageList1.GetIcon(0, icon, dsSelected, itImage);    
icon.handle := ImageList_GetIcon(ImageList1.Handle, 0, ILD_SELECTED);
```

Answer (score 2):

`BlendColor` property is used by the `Draw` method of the ImageList (or `DrawOverlay`).

```
ImageList1.Draw(Canvas, 0, 0, 0);
```

will use the color you specified in `BlendColor` when `DrawingStyle` is 'dsSelected' or 'dsFocus'.

The system, when you request it to do so, uses system colors, like 'highlight', 'selected'... Hence your call to the winapi function will result as such.

As there's no built-in way to request a blended icon from an ImageList, you can request it to do the blending for you over a bitmap and then convert it to an icon. You can find an example [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=913), for instance, that uses a temporary image list, or [here](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/graphic/convert_a_bitmap_to_an_icon.html). Or, you can get the list to draw the image and its mask to combine them into an icon, maybe like the below:

```
var
  Icon: TIcon;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  MaskBmp: TBitmap;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
begin
  Icon := TIcon.Create;

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    Bmp.Width := ImageList1.Width;
    Bmp.Height := ImageList1.Height;

    MaskBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      MaskBmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      MaskBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
      MaskBmp.Width := ImageList1.Width;
      MaskBmp.Height := ImageList1.Height;

      ImageList1.BlendColor := clRed;
      ImageList1.Draw(Bmp.Canvas, 0, 0, 0, dsSelected, itImage);
      ImageList1.Draw(MaskBmp.Canvas, 0, 0, 0, dsNormal, itMask);

      IconInfo.fIcon := True;
      IconInfo.hbmMask := MaskBmp.Handle;
      IconInfo.hbmColor := Bmp.Handle;

      Icon.Handle := CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);

    finally
      MaskBmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```